# Is there a simple way to check a function/expression for linearity in Java?

Tags: java, math

i try to find a way or a library to check if a function/expression is linear or not.

I am aware, that i can write a syntax check fpr the standart form of a linear function.
The challenge is, that it could be that the input is not standartisized.

For example:
2x+1

could be

(x+1)^2-x^2

Would be glad if somebody knows an easy way to get that working.

Update 1:
The solution should work for functions/expressions with 1..n variables.

Comment: If the input is not standardised, then you need to implement an equation solver (like they have at wolframalpha.com), which is not easy. Your best bet is probably to find a library that does this for you.

Comment: Well, it depends how much generality you need to have in your solution. In complete generality, you would need to write a lot of algebra code or import a library or something, e.g., call Maxima compiled with ABCL (Common Lisp for JVM). (By the way, is Java really a requirement? If not, you have wider options.) But maybe it's enough to just find the degree of each variable in the input. If the degree is zero or one, and there are no products of variables, then it's linear. One can almost do it with some terrible regex stuff. Again, it depends how general the solution needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

If approximation is fine, the easiest, generic way would be to evaluate the function at random points, and then check for linear changes in the output. 
i.e,

- Generate n random points `x_0, x_1, ... x_n`
- For each distinct pair `(x_i, x_j)` from it, check that `(f(x_i) - f(x_j))/(x_j - x_i)` is (almost) constant.

Comment: thanks for your fast answer, i was thinking about this aproach before, but i am not aware if this is fine for functions with more than one variable.

Comment: @Bömmel yes, it works just fine. You'd need to do something like principal components analysis to assess the linearity in general.

Comment: @Bömmel but, if you care about functions with more than one variable, say so in your question.

Comment: @Bömmel Yes, it should work but would be more complex and might be too slow. So what you want to do is to generate N coordinates (x,y) (instead of just x before), and to make sure that all the values f(x_i, y_i) lie on an n-dimensional plane instead of a line. I forget how to do that, long time. But you can look it up.